# what is the limitation on max cuda instances for video transcoding?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, cuda, hardware-acceleration, transcode, gstreamer

I have set up Nvidia V100 card on Azure Nc6s_v3 virtual machine. I have set up the latest CUDA driver and SDK. I compiled sample programs from "Video_Codec_SDK_9.0.20" and verified the max parallel transcode sessions using AppTrans binary. What I found is I can run 25 parallel transcode instances (25 decode, 25 encode), 26th instance will wait for anyone session to be deinitialized.

Can somebody explain, why is this limitation?

according to [article](https://developer.nvidia.com/video-encode-decode-gpu-support-matrix) there is no limitation on max concurrent sessions.

I compiled Gstreamer framework by enabling Nvidia plugins (nvdec and nvh264enc). I am seeing similar behavior here also. For 26th concurrent transcode session I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstNvH264Enc:nvh264enc0: Could not initialize supporting library.
Additional debug info:
gstnvbaseenc.c(423): gst_nv_base_enc_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstNvH264Enc:nvh264enc0:
Failed to create CUDA context, perhaps CUDA is not supported.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have encountered the artificial maximum number of simultaneous NVENC
video encoding sessions that is imposed by Nvidia on consumer-grade GPUs.

There a well-known patch for that on
[Github nvidia-patch](https://github.com/keylase/nvidia-patch/tree/master/win).

(I have never used this patch for Nvidia DLLs and cannot vouch that it will work.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response harry. I am using Nvidia GPU (Tesla V100) on Azure NC6s_v3 machine. Do u think its consumer-grade GPU?

Comment: Doesn't really sound like one. Perhaps there is a way to disable this limitation, but I don't think it's published. You could ask Nvidia Support for that, now that you have more information.